# Can a dog whistle frequency (23 to 54 kHz) by recorded on a CD?

Tags: recording, cd

Can a dog whistle frequency (23 to 54 kHz) by recorded on a CD and played on a CD player?For example can I be able to here music and transmitting the dog whistle frequency at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.

It's all to do with the sampling frequency & something known as the Nyquist Limit. Wikipedia has a description of this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency but don't be too surprised if your eyes glaze over at the first paragraph ;)

A CD is recorded at 44.1KHz - which you would think would be sufficient to get at least most of the sound - but the Nyquist Limit actually means that the maximum frequency that can be recorded is only half of that, i.e. 22.05KHz… below your dog whistle's frequencies.

That, though, is really only the first half of the problem.

The next is that no standard audio equipment is designed to record or play those frequencies anyway - as humans can't hear them, manufacturers don't see the need.
You would need some pretty specialist equipment to reproduce those frequencies & also some kind of computer hardware/software combination that could record them in the first place.